# Progress bar and percents

Tags: c#

I have a progress bar with Minimum=0 and Maximum=1000.
Now I have long FileSize=1454545454 and long BytesSent (example). How to calculate progress bar position? I always lose precision or something :/

Edit:
Solved... I forgot to cast like: (decimal) BytesSent. You guys did same:P
Thx for answers. Debbuger always helps.

Comment: Is this WPF or Winforms question?

Comment: Math question. Just need a formula, I'm very tired and I cannot think :/

Comment: Also consider setting Maximum to FileSize and then the progress would be BytesSent

Comment: I don't see any reason why you should be doing a cast to `decimal`. File sizes are `long`s and the Minimum and Maximum are likely `int`s.

Comment: Good point about the cast, it is needed when dividing an int by an int! I edited my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
progressBar.Value = (int)(
    progressBar.Minimum + ((double)BytesSent / FileSize) *
                          (progressBar.Maximum - progressBar.Minimum));
```

Or:

```
progressBar.Minimum = 0;
progressBar.Maximum = FileSize;
progressBar.Value = BytesSent;
```

Answer (score 3):

A progress bar is not a precision instrument — it's an approximate display of progress (and even if you showed the *exact* value, that would likely be an *incorrect* representation of the real progress).

So, you should simply do:

```
progressBar.Minimum = 0;
progressBar.Maximum = 100;
```

---

```
progressBar.Value = (BytesSent / FileSize) * progressBar.Maximum;
```

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de047043) is why I wouldn't bother using a more exact value:

> The value displayed by the ProgressBar only approximates the current value of the Value property.