# Progress bar and percent label

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

*First and foremost: **Yes I have searched and checked these**:*
* [VB - progress bar not incrementing correct amounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873061/vb-progress-bar-not-incrementing-correct-amounts)
* [Progress bar and percents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109576/progress-bar-and-percents)

**Question**: What is the best way to do a progress bar and a label for "percent" complete?

**My Scenario**: I have a check list box that I am looping thru and processing each item.

***What I have tried***: The first search result says to use the count as the max, as seen here:

```
ProgressBar1.Maximum = ListBox1.Items.Count
ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
```

This will work for the progress bar BUT not the text label, also if the items exceed 100, you will obviously get something like

> 231% Complete

etc..

My Idea was to use an IF statement and check to see if the total items is greater/less than 100 but thats where I have some issues.

This is my code, but please advise on what would be the best solution.

**My Code**:

```
Sub PercentComplete(ByVal Total As Long)

        Dim Notch As Integer = 100 / Total

        If Total > 100 Then
            'If the total is greater than 100
            Dim intPctText As Integer = Math.Round(Total / Notch, 10)
            lblPct.Text = intPctText & "%"
        Else
            'If the total is less than 100
            lblPct.Text = Notch.ToString & "%"
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: `Label1.Text = String.Format("{0}%",
                                ((ProgressBar1.Value / ProgressBar1.Maximum) * 100).ToString("F2"))`

Comment: @Plutonix: which could be simplified to `Label1.Text = String.Format("{0:F2}%", ((ProgressBar1.Value / ProgressBar1.Maximum) * 100))`